# Android studio spinner issue inside expandablelistview child

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-spinner

I would like to ask why this issue can happen?
I have expandable list view on the right side panel, when I expand the group, the child displays and it should hides all child view that is not enough to display, yet the spinner is still there at the bottom screen (while the other textview, edit text all are hidden). My children view is same as for all group expand. Can someone help me to solve this problem? I want to make the spinner hides as well. Thanks. I am using spinner with this attribute:

```
<Spinner
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

[Spinner displays instead of hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I65ni.png)

I'm sorry if it's double posted, as I don't know where should I type to search. Thank you very much.

My List Item xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/propertyEditText"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:background="@drawable/language_button"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test "
                android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test "
                android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/installmentEditText"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:background="@drawable/language_button"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My expandable list view get child method:

```
@Override
public View getRealChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    return convertView;
}
```

I'm using modified AnimatedExpandableListView, provided by 
https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView

Comment: show us more code

Comment: which code would you want to see? my xml or the expandable list view getChildView method?

Comment: I think the problem lies on the spinner? Because it can actually hides all the text views and edit texts, while the spinner is still there on my bottom screen (The picture, if it shows and does not hide everything, then it should show the "test" word beside the spinner as well).